# Bounty of other poster's question even though I gave an answer already

Tags: discussion, bounty

A user posted a question that I found very interesting.  I posted an answer to his question, but as it was a question about logic there are other possible answers.  I would be interested in seeing other people's responses, hopefully better than mine.

However, I realize it might seem strange or even a conflict to add a bounty to a question that I have tried to answer myself.  So I'm wondering:

1) Is it possible to add a bounty to a question even though I posted an answer?  I don't know yet because the time limit hasn't elapsed.

2) Is there any hard rule against it, or any reason not to?  I want to see more opinions on the question.

3) Supposing the poster accepts an answer before the bounty time limit elapses, is there a way to add a bounty or otherwise bring attention to the question?

Comment: Re: 3) bounties are completely unrelated to answer accepts.

Comment: Yes, go ahead and do it! A more typical (?) reason to give a bounty to a question that you have answered yourself, is that somebody else came up with such a sleek solution that you want reward it. Do collect a bit of rep before you get into that so that you won't lose any key privileges :-)

Comment: also it should be noted that even if you were to accept your answer (which you can't) still it would be morally fine to offer a bounty because you wouldn't net gain any rep from accepting your own answer (you lose the rep for the bounty and then would gain it back -  again though, you can't except your own answer so this is moot).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [MSE bounty faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/214632).

In particular, you are perfectly free to offer a bounty to a question you have already answered. The bounty, however, cannot go to your answer.

Other than that, there are a few details:

- The minimum bounty you can offer on a question you have answered is 100 rep points, instead of 50.
- The answer you reward with the bounty can differ from the answer the OP accepts.